# React Native vertically align 3 items in a row

Tags: react-native

I am struggling to vertically align these 3 items perfectly in the center. 2 icons and a text. Please refer to screenshot below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.rowContainer}>
    <View style={styles.rightSectRowContainer}>
        <Icon size={23} name='md-contact' color='dimgrey' />
        <Text style={styles.rowTitle}>Account</Text>
    </View>
    <Icon size={17} name='ios-arrow-forward' color='dimgrey' />
</TouchableOpacity>

rowContainer: {   
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: 'baseline',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    marginTop: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    borderRadius: 5
},
rightSectRowContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: "center"
},
```

Comment: just ```alignItems: 'center'``` instead of ```base-line``` in ```rowContainer```.

Comment: @cybercoder doesnt work, i tried that

Answer (score 0):

Please edit you `rightSectRowContainer` style as follows...

```
rightSectRowContainer: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: "row",
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: "center",
},
```

Or, if you want to align all 3 items to the center, you have to do

```
justifyContent: "center",
```

in `rowContainer`. That means,

```
rowContainer: {   
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: 'baseline',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    marginTop: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    borderRadius: 5
},
```

Comment: this doesnt work. what i need is to align vertically in the center. horizontally the alignment is already correct